# Returned reference to string literal (passed as parameter) is accessible in calling function, however, returned object storing the reference is empty

Tags: c++

I'm passing a string literal to a function that simply returns back a const reference to it. In the calling function, the string is accessible and printed.

However, in another function, I'm instantiating a class that holds a const reference to the string literal. Returning this object back prints nothing in the calling function.

Environment: Visual Studio 2017 (/std:c++=17)

This seems unusual. Any leads?

```
class Test {
private:
    const string& str_;

public:
    Test(const string& str)
        : str_{str}
    {}

    Test(const Test&) = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test&) = delete;

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Test& t) {
        return (out << t.str_);
    }
};

const Test& returnString2(const string& str) {        
    return Test{ str };
}

const string& returnString1(const string& str) {
    return str;
}

void testRef() {
    cout << "testRef: " << returnString2("Roofus") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: returnString2() returns a reference to an object that is no more alive.

Comment: `return (out << t.str_);` -- This looks strange.  Overloaded `<<` would write to `out`, and then `return out;` on a separate line.  `out << t.str_; return out;`

Comment: cont Obj& f() { return Obj();} returns a ref to a temporary: UDB. If you think about it, why would you want a reference to an instance of Obj you just created?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that's fine. overloaded ostream operator<< returns ostream&. Hence, (out << t_str_) returns ostream& that is in turn returned as ostream& from the overloaded method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
const Test& returnString2(const string& str) {        
    return Test{ str };
}
```

You are creating a temporary `Test`, that you are returning a reference to. But this temporary is destroyed at the end of the function resulting in undefined behaviour. This has nothing to do with the passed in `str` ref - its the temporary `Test` object that has been destroyed. The reference to `str` is still happily exiting.

In:

```
const string& returnString1(const string& str) {
    return str;
}
```

You are simply returning the ref passed in - this still exists when the function returns and so `cout << "testRef: " << returnString2("Roofus") << "\n";` is fine.

In fact a good compiler would warn you about this (not sure what visual studio does - but I am sure you can turn such warnings on): https://godbolt.org/z/E4s46bdEP

Comment: Thanks @code_fodder. I missed the warnings on output window.